# Why is client getting EOF on async_write?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing an asynchronous server using boost::asio. I changed boost HTTP server example to use only simple protobufs. Now client gets `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>: read: End of file` error when server's trying to send message using async_write.

I have tried sync and async clients, different types of buffers but the problem is still there. All the things are going well until async_write.

```
        void TConnection::DoRead() {
            std::cout << "Reading data" << std::endl;
            auto self(shared_from_this());
            Socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(Buffer),
                                    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
                                    {
                                        if (!ec) {
                                            TRequestParser::ResultType result;
                                            TMessage request;
                                            request.Parse(Buffer.data(), bytes_transferred);
                                            Reply = MasterPtr->HandleMessange(request);
                                            std::cout << "Replying: " << Reply.Content << std::endl;
                                            DoWrite();
                                        } else if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
                                            ConnectionManager.Stop(shared_from_this());
                                        }
                                    });
        }

        void TConnection::DoWrite() {
            std::cout << "Writing data" << std::endl;
            auto self(shared_from_this());
            std::cout << "Replying2: " << Reply.Content << std::endl;
            Reply.ToStreamBuf(&Streambuf);
            std::cout << "Now I'm gonna write" << std::endl;
            std::cout << Streambuf.size() << std::endl;
            boost::asio::async_write(Socket, Streambuf,
                                     [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t)
                                     {
                                         std::cout << "Oh, handled" << std::endl;
                                         if (!ec)
                                         {
                                             // Initiate graceful connection closure.
                                             boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
                                             Socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both,
                                                              ignored_ec);
                                         }
                                         if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
                                         {
                                             ConnectionManager.Stop(shared_from_this());
                                         }
                                     });
        }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because you're shutting down the socket.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, but it's necessary for `boost::asio::read`, isn't it? I thought that it's reading data until socket is shutting down

Comment: No, it isn't necessary for `boost::asio::read()`, and no it doesn't read until shutdown, and your code proves that if there was a shutdown it reports end of file, just like every other read method on the planet.

Comment: I've already solved the problem using `read_some` but why do we close a socket in HTTP server example in boost docs? If I use `read_some` and don't close a socket everything is ok but when I use `read()` and don't close a socket, I get infinite execution on this line. Should I manually add `\0` into the end of the buffer?